# How to block and unblock a servlet thread?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, servlets

I have a spring `@RestController`, thus a simple `servlet`.

If the servlet is invoked concurrently with the same values (naming a "hash" in this example), I want to block all but the first servlet. And when this one finished, I want to free the blocked ones.

As a solution, I thought of adding the hash to a `ConcurrentHashMap`, and also adding the servlet threads to that hashmap as value for the hash key.

But how could I add a running java thread there?

The following pseudo code illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
@RestController
public class MyService {
    //a map blocking any concurrent process on the same hash value
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<Object>> map;

    @RequestMethod
    public String myXmlMethod(Param params) {
        String hash = params.getHash(); ////assume a value identifying a certain form of logic

        if (!map.contains(hash)) {
            //here no concurrent task is running, so block the hash until removal
            map.put(hash, new ArrayList<Object>());
            callLongRunningTaskAndWriteToDB();

            List<Object> threads = map.get(hash);
            map.remove(hash); //free the hash

            //interrupt any waiting threads, as the hash completed now
            if (threads != null && !threads.isEmpty()) {
                for (thread : threads) {
                    thread.interruptWait();
                }
            }
        } else {
            //this way the servlet thread cannot continue until the timout occurs,
            //or the servlet thread is canceled by the main thread in the concurrent hashmap
            thread = new Thread(this, Timeout.SECONDS(30));
            map.get(hash).add(thread);
            waitForThreadTimeoutOrInterrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** But how can I actually get a handle of the current executing "thread" of the method? So that I can add it to the Map, and wait and interrupt on it?

Comment: A Spring `@RestControler` is not a servlet. Spring's `DispatcherServlet` is a servlet.

Comment: Well at least it creates a servlet that is accessible by get queries. That is what matters for this question.

Comment: You really don't want to be blocking servlet handling threads though. Use async to handle all this stuff if you must. Spring offers `DeferredResult` and `Callable` to achieve this.

Comment: Because describing a problem correctly is important, just note that `I want to block all but the first servlet` is misleading. A _servlet_ doesn't get blocked. A Thread does. There is no _first servlet_. Your container is going to create a single `DispatcherServlet` (in almost all scenarios), and your Spring context will only contain a singleton bean for your `@RestController` annotated class. All requests go through these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a `ConcurrentMap` of `FutureTask` as below:

**We first define the `ConcurrentMap`:**

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, FutureTask<MyResult>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

**We implement the logic that prevents 2 threads doing the same task at the same time:**

```
@RequestMethod
public String myXmlMethod(Param params) {
    String hash = params.getHash(); ////assume a value identifying a certain form of logic
    FutureTask<MyResult> task = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<MyResult>() {
        @Override
        public MyResult call() throws Exception {
            // My task here
        }
    });
    // This boolean means we are the first to insert the entry
    boolean inserted = true;
    try {
        FutureTask<MyResult> previous = map.putIfAbsent(hash, task);
        if (previous == null) {
            // The task has not been defined so far so we execute it
            task.run();
        } else {
            // the task has already been defined
            task = previous;
            inserted = false;
        }
        // we wait until we get the result
        return task.get();
    } finally {
        // Clean up the per key map but only if our insertion succeeded and with our future
        if (inserted) {
           map.remove(hash, task);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would executing the logic inside a `FutureTask` have impact on performance?

Comment: Not really what can have impact on performance (if you use an old version of Java) is calling the result of the task with task.get() if you do it too ofter as it is a synchronized access. Starting from Java 8, it is lock free so this issue doesn't exist anymore. BTW If you use Java 8, you can of course use a lambda expression to create your FutureTask

Comment: I just learned that this can be further optimized using `@Async public FutureTask<MyResult> longRunningTask()`.

Comment: I never tried because I don't like Spring much but is seems to do the trick so you should propose it as answer to your question. What I don't like with Spring is the fact that it is too intrusive (and not really standard), you want only a little thing and you get the whole stuff with many things useless for you, but as you obviously use already Spring it is not a issue for you :-)

Comment: As I'm anyways using `spring-boot` that's not an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is simply how to get the current thread, you can get the current thread using the static method [`currentThread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()) of the class `Thread`.

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()):

> **Returns a reference to the currently executing thread** object.

Comment: Would this help in pausing and continuing the servlet thread? I mean, how could I pause the thread, and signal a continuation on it, of course without cancelling the thread. Just cancelling the wait time.

Comment: You need to wait on a particular object. The thread will sleep until another thread call the notify or notifyAll on the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current thread as `Thread.currentThread` if that is your question, but I see you're trying to implement a kind of mutual exclusion for your `callLongRunningTaskAndWriteToDB()`, so only one thread will execute that code.

Won't be better to use a Java based mechanism like `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`? Even more, you can set your `callLongRunningTaskAndWriteToDB` method in a Runnable task and get access to that through singleton and make sure only one thread execute the method...